# C++ print value of a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, printing, stdout, cout

I have an array of double pointers, but every time I try do print one of the values the address gets printed. How do I print the actual value?

cout << arr[i] ?  cout << &arr[i] ? they both print the address

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it's really an array of (initialized) double pointers, i.e.:

```
double *arr[] = ...
// Initialize individual values
```

all you need is:

```
cout << *arr[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

cout << *(arr[i]) will print the value.

Answer (score 1):

`cout << *(arr[i]);`

Comment: @Potatoswatter. The compiler might not, and technically neither do I, because I can remember the operator precedence if I have to. But they certainly improve things.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: parens aren't needed for `5 + 112 % 65 ^ 1 / 5.5 && bar || foo^2 << 5` either, but `(((5 + (112 % 65)) ^ (1 / 5.5)) && bar) || (foo^(2 << 5))` is much more clear

Comment: +1 for parenthesis, I always parenthesise that kind of expression.

Answer (score 0):

If "arr" is declared as

```
double* arr[..];
```

Then you would use:

```
cout << *(arr[i])
```